# Webkit browsers: border-right property issue

Tags: css, webkit

I don't get why the "border-right: 1px solid white;" property in my menu doesn't work in webkit browsers Safari and Google Chrome...

As you can see there is not white line on the right of PRODUCTEN.

It works perfectly on Firefox and IE.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="/node/324" id="dhtml_menu-3841" class="active">PRODUCTEN </a>
```

Just take away the whitespace after "PRODUCTEN" - it should work fine.